# Getting an error from cete Dynamic pdf: ceTe.DynamicPDF.Imaging.ImageParsingException: TIFF Compression value 8 (Flate/Deflate) is not supported

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error from cete DynamicPdf, any help would be appreciated, I have posted it on their forum but not getting a response. It happens when I call the draw method to create a Pdf after merging several documents into one.
Is there a workaround for it?

Stacktrace follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "(unknown)", line 235, in ceTe.DynamicPDF.Imaging.TiffImageData.a()
File "(unknown)", line 19, in ceTe.DynamicPDF.Imaging.TiffImageData.c()
File "(unknown)", line unknown, in ceTe.DynamicPDF.Imaging.TiffImageData.Draw(ceTe.DynamicPDF.IO.OperatorWriter writer, System.Single pdfX, System.Single pdfY, System.Single width, System.Single height)
File "(unknown)", line 617, in ceTe.DynamicPDF.PageElements.Image.DrawRotated(ceTe.DynamicPDF.IO.PageWriter writer)
File "(unknown)", line 103, in ceTe.DynamicPDF.PageElements.RotatingPageElement.Draw(ceTe.DynamicPDF.IO.PageWriter writer)
File "(unknown)", line unknown, in ceTe.DynamicPDF.PageElements.Group.Draw(ceTe.DynamicPDF.IO.PageWriter writer)
File "(unknown)", line 14, in ceTe.DynamicPDF.Page.b(ceTe.DynamicPDF.IO.PageWriter A_0)
File "(unknown)", line 136, in ceTe.DynamicPDF.Page.fd(ceTe.DynamicPDF.IO.DocumentWriter A_0, System.Int32 A_1, System.Int32 A_2)
File "(unknown)", line 178, in ceTe.DynamicPDF.Page.a(ceTe.DynamicPDF.IO.DocumentWriter A_0, System.Int32 A_1, System.Int32 A_2, System.Int32 A_3)
File "(unknown)", line 166, in zz93.b1.f()
File "(unknown)", line 419, in zz93.b1.Draw()
File "(unknown)", line 1, in ceTe.DynamicPDF.Document.Draw(System.IO.Stream stream)
File "(unknown)", line 15, in ceTe.DynamicPDF.Document.Draw()
File "C:\Users\Simon\Source\Workspaces\PubManager\PubManager\PdfManager\Printing.cs", line 1505, in PubManager.PdfManager.Printing+d__3.MoveNext()
File "(unknown)", line 12, in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
File "(unknown)", line 40, in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task)
File "C:\Users\Simon\Source\Workspaces\PubManager\PubManager\PubManager\Controllers\PageLayoutController.cs", line 598, in PubManager.Controllers.PageLayoutController+d__24.MoveNext()
File "(unknown)", line 12, in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
File "(unknown)", line 40, in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task)
File "(unknown)", line unknown, in System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)
File "(unknown)", line unknown, in System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)
File "(unknown)", line unknown, in System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)
File "(unknown)", line 20, in System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
File "(unknown)", line 134, in System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+AsyncInvocationWithFilters+<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
File "(unknown)", line 134, in System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+AsyncInvocationWithFilters+<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
File "(unknown)", line unknown, in System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)
File "(unknown)", line unknown, in System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21+<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
File "(unknown)", line unknown, in System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)
ceTe.DynamicPDF.Imaging.ImageParsingException: TIFF Compression value 8 (Flate/Deflate) is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like TIFF images with compression value 7 or above are not suported. Have a look at this thread:
https://www.dynamicpdf.com/forums/core-suite-for-net-v9/tiff-compression-value-7-extended-jpeg-not-supported

Comment: Thanks for that, I guess my googling needs some improvement :)